# Cannot run python3 on macOs. I getting an error as "killed"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a lambda function with sam-cli. And I installed python3.8 after removing 3.9.x etc.

Finally I checked my python version, So I get an message like that:

```
$ python3 --version
[1]    68567 killed     python3 --version
```

Also just python3 return same error.

```
$ python3
[1]    68586 killed     python3
```

Btw I getting outputs like that:

```
$ whereis python3
/usr/bin/python3

$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
```

How can I debugging this type error? Why Im getting this type error? Please Help!

Comment: Seems like you have broken the default python 3.6 and are trying to start it. Need much more details on what you did to "install" and "remove" to help.

Comment: does it happen when you do `$ /usr/bin/python3` or `$ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3` too?

Comment: I believe in [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/284824/remove-and-reinstall-python-on-mac-can-i-trust-these-old-references) thread you'll find all the leads you need to fix your issue.